# text not showing how it should be in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of text that looks like this:

```
<p> We recently reduced the number of savings accounts we offer. I welcomed this because I think
 members find it confusing to look through tables of lots of slightly different accounts, all 
with advantages and disadvantages. I think it affects their trust in us. But I don’t understand 
why we haven’t applied this to children’s accounts of all things. Since children don’t pay tax, 
why do they need an ISA as well as a children’s savings account? Children (and their parents) 
are the last people we want to confuse as they could be customers for life. And why is our 
children’s savings account called the ‘Smart Limited Access’? It doesn’t strike me as being very 
self-explanatory or child friendly. How about just ‘Nationwide Young Saver Account’?

I’d be grateful if you could clear this up for me.

Best regards,

Vanessa</p>
```

However when it is put into html it ignores this layout and has it has one line. How can I keep it as its orginal text

Comment: By using <br> tags, or set width of p/container... But you will need br tags, anyway....

Comment: That's how HTML work. If you want to follow the layout, use the `<pre>` tag... or CSS `white-space : pre;`

Comment: It does not have “one line”, unless you are doing something odd in CSS. And what do you mean by keeping it “as its original text”? Do you want to present it as plain text and not HTML at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<pre>` thats instead of `<p>` tags to keep the formating the same.

```
<pre>Now
Line endings
Are conserved !</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put each line in separate `<p>` tags.

```
<p>We recently reduced ... 'Nationwide Young Saver Account'?</p>
<p>I'd be grateful if you could clear this up for me</p>
<p>Best regards,</p>
<p>Vanessa</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way would be to set css property of the `p` tag

```
<p class="makeItLookTheSame"> We recently reduced the number of savings accounts we offer. I welcomed this because I think
 members find it confusing to look through tables of lots of slightly different accounts, all 
with advantages and disadvantages. I think it affects their trust in us. But I don’t understand 
why we haven’t applied this to children’s accounts of all things. Since children don’t pay tax, 
why do they need an ISA as well as a children’s savings account? Children (and their parents) 
are the last people we want to confuse as they could be customers for life. And why is our 
children’s savings account called the ‘Smart Limited Access’? It doesn’t strike me as being very 
self-explanatory or child friendly. How about just ‘Nationwide Young Saver Account’?

I’d be grateful if you could clear this up for me.

Best regards,

Vanessa</p>
```

And so in your css file:

```
.makeItLookTheSame{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> We recently reduced the number of savings accounts we offer. I welcomed this because I think
 members find it confusing to look through tables of lots of slightly different accounts, all 
with advantages and disadvantages. I think it affects their trust in us. But I don’t understand 
why we haven’t applied this to children’s accounts of all things. Since children don’t pay tax, 
why do they need an ISA as well as a children’s savings account? Children (and their parents) 
are the last people we want to confuse as they could be customers for life. And why is our 
children’s savings account called the ‘Smart Limited Access’? It doesn’t strike me as being very 
self-explanatory or child friendly. How about just ‘Nationwide Young Saver Account’?</p>

<p>I’d be grateful if you could clear this up for me.</p>

<p>Best regards,<br>

Vanessa</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <meta name="description" 
              content="" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />
    </head>


 <body>

  <div id="yourText">
     Say something here
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Create a file called style.css in the same folder.
Insert this:

```
#yourText
{
width: 400px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You will have to set `<br />` afther each end of sentence and adjust the width (400).
Delete the border, it's just so you can understand how it works